# Django model viewset built-in delete method does not work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I have model viewset that I did not override it:

```
class RolesAndPermissionsViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = RoleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoleSerializer
```

the urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'role', RolesAndPermissionsViewSet, basename='roles_and_permissions')

urlpatterns = [] + router.urls
```

serializer:

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = RequestPermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "permissions",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        permissions = validated_data.pop('permissions', [])
        print(permissions)
        role = super(RoleSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for permission in permissions:
            role.permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(id=permission['id']))
        return role
```

and in the postman:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L6MH.png)

but it doesn't delete the row from my django admin.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your serializer operates on a different model (`Role`) as your view set's queryset (`RoleModel`).

Comment: No bro i import it as (RoleModel) @schwobaseggl

Comment: `from account.models import Role as RoleModel`

Comment: Cool bro, but invisibly renaming (nowhere in the question does it show this) it makes it hard to help ya.

Comment: What happens if you call `role.delete()` manually on a Role?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to include a `/` at the end of the URL in postman.

So instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/role/3,

You should do [http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/role/3`/`](http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/role/3%60/%60).

If you don't want to use Postman, you could also use the built-in Browsable API from djangorest-framework as shown below.

Just input the specific item in the URL like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/role/3/ and press the delete button to delete a single record with `pk=3`.
[image]